# Reading from csv to numpy array

Tags: pandas, csv, numpy, machine-learning

I'm trying to read csv file in order to read file in chunks. My aim is to store every chunk in numpy array.

I saved data converting numpy to pandas DataFrame and than using:

```
df.to_csv("train_data.csv",header=None,index=None,compression='gzip')
```

---

First, reading it with `pd.read_csv`

```
reader = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv",iterator=True,header=None,
                      dtype={0:np.float64,1:np.float64,2:np.float64,3:np.int32,4:np.int32,5:np.int32)
```

After that, trying to convert pandas to numpy array, but since I have nested arrays, it gives error about string to float conversion.

Every row has shape (1,6) and it is something like this:

```
[22. 22. 22.68715685 12.278416...] [22.7081927] [22.59577521 12.05934614 22.80610344 23.107679...] [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [0] [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]\n [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]\n [0 0 ...]
```

There are 6 concatenated arrays at each row in the shape of:

```
(1 5), (1), (1,5), (1,8), (1), (144,256)
```

When I subscript to first part of the row, it is in between quotes and the type is string, also it can be seen at the end of the row there are `'\n'` charcters between arrays.

How can I turn this csv file to numpy array quickly?

Comment: Since you have successfully read the csv in pandas, let's focus on extracting `values` from the dataframe.  The csv is no longer useful.  Alternatively, describe the `csv`, with some sample rows, and let's focus on reading it with `numpy` functions.

Comment: Here is the first row of the csv: `['[22 22 22 22 22]', '[22.68715685]', '[12.27841683 22.99721452 22.7081927  22.59577521 12.05934614]', '[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]', '[0]', '[[ 0  0  0 ... 76 76 76]\n [ 0  0  0 ... 76 76 76]\n [ 0  0  0 ... 76 76 76]\n ...\n [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]\n [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]\n [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]]']`
Btw, the values at the question is a row from pandas DataFrame.

Comment: If the original dataframe had object dtypes containing arrays, apparently the `to_csv` has saved string representations of those arrays to the file.  That's not a 'normal' `csv` format.  And apparently the `load_csv` has also  just read the strings without trying to parse them.  What's the `df.dtypes` for both original and loaded df?

Comment: I can imagine creating a structured array with a compound `dtype` like `[('f0',int,(5,)), ('f1', float), ('f2', float, (5,)), .... ('f5', float, (144,256))]`.  `genfromtxt` can load a flat row into such a structure if there are enough numbers.  But there's nothing in `numpy` that will readily handle these strings.  I don't know if `pandas` has anything useful or not.

Comment: I tried to construct a dataframe from an structured array as I just described, and found it not accept it.  A simple structured array with scalar fields is fine, but not one with arrays.  I think you need to tell us more about the original dataframe.

Comment: The ellipses in the `csv` are real - `tocsv` is writing the `str(...)` format of reach object dtype element.  So there's no way of recovering the original dataframe from the `csv`.

Comment: Yes, I also realized it when I tried to break down every array in order to create piece by piece. I thougt that they are shortening. How can `to_csv` function write df like this, isn’t that supposed to create a csv from df. Is it just directing output to file

Comment: `In [79]: for i,c in enumerate(num_arr[0]):
    ...:     s=''
    ...:     if i==5:
    ...:         for j in range(len(c)):
    ...:             s += " ".join(str(e) for e in c[j].tolist())
    ...:             s += ':'
    ...:         f.write(s)
    ...:         continue
    ...:     s = " ".join(str(e) for e in c)
    ...:     f.write(s+',')`
I wrote an iterative solution while writing numpy to csv, but this is just for the first row, there are approx. 100k row. Is there any other possilble solution that can perform bettter than this?